# Using “sapply” in a function with conditional argument(s)

Tags: r

Consider the following functions:-

```
abc<-function(n,alpha, sigma2=NULL){
  if(!is.null(sigma2)){

      return(qnorm(1-alpha, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE, log.p=FALSE)) 
  }
  else
  {

      return(qt(1-alpha, n-1, lower.tail=TRUE, log.p=FALSE)) 
  }

}

abc1<-function(n, k, alpha, sigma2=NULL){

  c1<-abc(n, alpha, sigma2)
  Q<-matrix(10, nrow=k, ncol=1)
  i=0
  for(j in 1:k)
  {
    if(Q[j,1]>c1)
      i=i+1

  }
  return(i/k)
}
```

My interest is mainly on the second function which has a conditional argument. The function is working fine with both `sigma2` being `NULL` or it is given:-

```
> abc1(10,10, 0.01, 1)
[1] 1
> abc1(10,10, 0.01)
[1] 1
```

However, whenever I try to use `sapply` with `sigma2` being `NULL` and other arguments fixed at some value I get an error like this :-

```
n1<-1:100
> sapply(n1, abc1, k=10,alpha=0.01)
Error in if (Q[j, 1] > c1) i = i + 1 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In qt(1 - alpha, n - 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) : NaNs produced
```

I do not know where I am making mistake. Could anyone tell me how can I rectify this problem?

Comment: What is `n1` here?

Comment: sorry I forgot to metion :- ```n1<-1:100```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't evaluate `qt(1-alpha, n-1, lower.tail=TRUE, log.p=FALSE)`for `n = 1` since you are actually asking for a quantile of a T distribution with 0 df.

I don't know what's the purpose of those function (so maybe the following output is still wrong), but if you change `n1 <- 2:100` then it should work, i.e.

```r
# Function definition
abc <- function(n, alpha, sigma2 = NULL) {
  if (!is.null(sigma2)) {
    return(qnorm(1 - alpha, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE))
  }
  else {
    return(qt(1 - alpha, n - 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE))
  }
}

abc1 <- function(n, k, alpha, sigma2 = NULL) {
  c1 <- abc(n, alpha, sigma2)
  Q <- matrix(10, nrow = k, ncol = 1)
  i <- 0
  for (j in 1:k)
  {
    if (Q[j, 1] > c1) {
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
  return(i / k)
}

# Note that it starts from 2
n1 <- 2:100

sapply(n1, abc1, k = 10, alpha = 0.01)
#>  [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [39] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [77] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>